# I wonder why this button doesn't work. Am I wrong with the code?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```css
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Food List1',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: placeSection,
          ),
          drawer: Container(
              child:
          Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 150,
                  child:DrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '현대제철 구내식당',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),

                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.home,size:60,),

                  title: Text("홈(메인페이지)",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                  onTap: () { Navigator.push(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyApp2()));},
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Image.asset('images/Da.png'),
                  title: Text("당진 구내식당",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DJPage1()));
                  },
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Image.asset('images/ic.png'),
                  title: Text("인천 구내식당",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  onTap: () {Navigator.push(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => IcPage1()));},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),),
          body: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DJPage2()));
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  iconSize: 55,
                ),
                top: 370,
                right: 360,
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DJPage1()));
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                  iconSize: 55,
                ),
                top: 370,
                left: 360,
              ),
```

click arrow btuuons  it`s not working.

IS therea a problem with the code??

child iconbutton
I would appreciate it if you write down various things and give me a hint as to whether this is a different problem.

If the widget is the problem, what to fix?

Even if I try to find out what the problem is, I am worried that the code works normally.

Comment: Are you using Positioned widget inside Stack or anyother widget.

Comment: Yes I am using  stack widget //
body: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(

Comment: Code is correct and it's working, may be other widgets affecting the button. Can you put your full code of build method?

Comment: Edit my post.  Would you please look again?

Comment: again i checked with your code. its working. while running in my mobile i change position value only for left and right as 260. its working. i checked this by adding print statement.

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` renders it's widgets from bottom to top. The first widgets you add to the `Stack` will be on the bottom, the last ones will be on top of them.

You didn't provide a full code of your `Stack`, but I am assuming there are other widgets there, transparent ones, that are on top of those buttons and absorbing their clicks.